# jquery tablesorter set custom value for filter select options

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

If i have a td cell value as follows

```
<td data-column="0">
            <a title="Test " href="..."><span class="inlineicon icon-object-cl_colo" title="Colo"></span> Test</a><span style="display: none">KEY</span></td>
```

I want the filter option to display the select value as `KEY` and the display text to be `Test`. but currently it just appends both strings together.

I tried doing this which works on initial load. but any chnages to the table seems to still load the old values

```
$table.on('tablesorter-ready', function(e) {
                var array = $.tablesorter.filter.getOptionSource( $table, 0, true );
                // build options
                var opts = '<option value=""></option>';
                for ( index = 0; index < array.length; index++ ) {
                    if(array[ index ].text.length > 0) {
                        var split = array[ index ].text.split('|');
                        opts += '<option value="' + split[0] + '">' + split[1] + '</option>';
                    }
                }
                $.tablesorter.filter.buildSelect( $table, 0, opts, true );
            });
```

Comment: Try putting `KEY` into a `data-text` attribute on the `<td>` - see the [textAttribute option to change it](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#textattribute).

Comment: I tried this but this uses the `data-text` as value and display on the options list now. `<option parsed="KEY" data-function-name="KEY" value="KEY">KEY</option>`

Comment: Would you please [modify this demo to show the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/)

Comment: here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/shorif2000/9ew36hnd/ note the ajax response will be different when i trigger filter select